# How to uninstall Notepad++ using Ansible when we don't have product ID?

Tags: ansible, notepad++, uninstallation

---

- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
  notepadplusplus_home_dir_un: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\uninstall.exe"

  tasks:

  - name: uninstall notepadplusplus
    win_shell: |
    "{{ notepadplusplus_home_dir_un }}" /S
    args:
    executable: cmd
    register: uninstaller
    tags: ['uninstall']

When I run this, I'll get result as changed=1 but Notepad++ is not uninstalling in server. Any suggestion for this?

Post result:

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [X.X.X.X]

TASK [uninstall notepadplusplus] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [X.X.X.X]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
X.X.X.X                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

When I run this, I'll get result as changed=1 but Notepad++ is not uninstalling in server. Any suggestion for this? Even I tried with win_package but I couldn't find product_ID , so I specified as null and ran but still changed =1 but not uninstalling Notepad++.

Comment: If you file a question, [maybe on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) I can provide an answer and explain what the `product_id` is and how to find it out ...